# How can I use void template type for compile-time conditional code and static_assert?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I have traverse function which invokes callback for every element and want to implement it's logic extension with non-default arguments at compile-time like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<
    typename Odds = void,
    typename Evens = void,
    typename Skip = void
>
void iterate(
    const auto & on_element,
    const auto & skip 
) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++ i ) {
        if constexpr ( ! is_same_v< Skip, void > ) {
            if ( skip.find( i ) != skip.end() )
                continue;
        }

        if ( i % 2 == 1 ) {
            if constexpr ( is_same_v< Odds, void > )
                on_element( i );
        }
        else {
            if constexpr ( is_same_v< Evens, void > )
                on_element( i );
        }

        static_assert(
            is_same_v< Odds, void > || is_same_v< Evens, void >,
            "Either odds or evens are required to get traversed"
        );
    }
}

int main() {
    const auto & on_element = []( const int & i ) {
        cout << "    " << i << endl;
    };

    cout << "Whole range:" << endl;
    iterate( on_element );

    cout << "Should skip specified elements:" << endl;
    iterate( on_element, { 1, 2, 3 } );

    cout << "Should traverse only evens:" << endl;
    iterate< bool >( on_element );

    cout << "Should traverse only odds:" << endl;
    iterate< void, bool >( on_element );

    //should NOT compile if uncomment:
    //iterate< bool, bool >( on_element );
}
```

But it doesn't compile with `g++ -std=gnu++2a -fconcepts main.cpp -o main`:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:42:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘iterate(const main()::<lambda(const int&)>&)’
   42 |     iterate( on_element );
      |                         ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Odds, class Evens, class Skip, class auto:11, class auto:12> void iterate(const auto:11&, const auto:12&)’
   10 | void iterate(
      |      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:42:25: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   42 |     iterate( on_element );
      |                         ^
main.cpp:45:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘iterate(const main()::<lambda(const int&)>&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   45 |     iterate( on_element, { 1, 2, 3 } );
      |                                      ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Odds, class Evens, class Skip, class auto:11, class auto:12> void iterate(const auto:11&, const auto:12&)’
   10 | void iterate(
      |      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:45:38: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘auto:12’
   45 |     iterate( on_element, { 1, 2, 3 } );
      |                                      ^
main.cpp:48:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘iterate<bool>(const main()::<lambda(const int&)>&)’
   48 |     iterate< bool >( on_element );
      |                                 ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Odds, class Evens, class Skip, class auto:11, class auto:12> void iterate(const auto:11&, const auto:12&)’
   10 | void iterate(
      |      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:48:33: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   48 |     iterate< bool >( on_element );
      |                                 ^
main.cpp:51:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘iterate<void, bool>(const main()::<lambda(const int&)>&)’
   51 |     iterate< void, bool >( on_element );
      |                                       ^
main.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Odds, class Evens, class Skip, class auto:11, class auto:12> void iterate(const auto:11&, const auto:12&)’
   10 | void iterate(
      |      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:51:39: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   51 |     iterate< void, bool >( on_element );
      |                                       ^
```

Is there a way I can implement it in C++?
Maybe there are better compile-time techniques for achieving desired behavior?

Comment: Since you're not using the template types for anything other than testing them against `void`, you should consider using `bool` template parameters.

Comment: @IlCapitano I guess I mentally stuck to `auto` too much and couldn't figure out how to check if argument was passed at all ^^, but it's `bool T = true` indeed. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you should avoid `auto` type parameters, in this case.

I propose the following code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template<
    bool Odds = true,
    bool Evens = true,
    typename Func,
    typename Skip = bool
>
void iterate(
    Func const & on_element,
    Skip const & skip = false
) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++ i ) {
        if constexpr ( ! is_same_v< Skip, bool > ) {
            if ( skip.find( i ) != skip.end() )
                continue;
        }

        if ( i % 2 == 1 ) {
            if constexpr ( Odds )
                on_element( i );
        }
        else {
            if constexpr ( Evens )
                on_element( i );
        }

        static_assert(
            Odds || Evens,
            "Either odds or evens are required to get traversed"
        );
    }
}

int main() {
    const auto & on_element = []( const int & i ) {
        cout << "    " << i << endl;
    };

    cout << "Whole range:" << endl;
    iterate( on_element );

    cout << "Should skip specified elements:" << endl;
    iterate( on_element, std::set{ 1, 2, 3 } );

    cout << "Should traverse only evens:" << endl;
    iterate< false >( on_element );

    cout << "Should traverse only odds:" << endl;
    iterate< true, false >( on_element );

    // should NOT compile if uncomment:
    // iterate< false, false >( on_element );
}
```

Comment: I would probably have `enum class Parity {Odd, Even, Both};` to avoid impossible combination.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<
  bool Odds = false,
  bool Evens = false,
  bool Skip = false // or really, true: why pass skip if we won't use it?
>
void iterate(
  const auto & on_element,
  const auto & skip
)
```

and write another overload:

```
template<
  bool Odds = false,
  bool Evens = false
> // no bool Skip; lack of arg is enough
void iterate(
  const auto & on_element
)
{
  iterate<Odds, Evens, false>(on_element);
}
```

then replace `! is_same_v< Skip, void >` with `Skip` and similar for odds/evens.

Also

```
static_assert( !Skip||!std::is_same_v<decltype(skip), const int&>, "You must pass a 2nd argument" );
```

would be good for quality of life.

Comment: Sorry but... calling `iterate(on_element)` (without a second argument) I get a "error: no matching function for call to 'iterate(const main()::<lambda(const int&)>&)'", "note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto:12'" from g++ 11.0.0 and a similar error ("candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'skip:auto'") from clang++ 12.0.0 (wandbox). Are you sure that in C++20 it's possible express a default value for an `auto` argument?

Comment: @max no, not sure; fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps simplify

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

auto Odds = [](auto&& i) { return i % 2 == 0; };
auto Evens = [](auto&& i) { return i % 2 == 1; };
auto None = [](auto&&) { return false; };

template<class...Ts>
struct These
{
    constexpr These(Ts... args)
    : args_ { args... }
    {}

    template<class Arg>
    bool operator()(Arg&& i) const
    {
        return std::any_of(
            std::begin(args_), 
            std::end(args_), 
            [i](auto x) { return x == i; }
        );
    }

    std::array<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts)> args_;
};

template<
    typename Skip = decltype(None)
>
void iterate(
    const auto & on_element,
    Skip&& skip = Skip()
) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++ i ) {
        if (skip(i))
            continue;
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    const auto & on_element = []( const int & i ) {
        std::cout << "    " << i << std::endl;
    };

    std::cout << "Whole range:" << std::endl;
    iterate( on_element );

    std::cout << "Should skip specified elements:" << std::endl;
    iterate( on_element, These( 1, 2, 3 ));

    std::cout << "Should traverse only evens:" << std::endl;
    iterate( on_element , Evens);

    std::cout << "Should traverse only odds:" << std::endl;
    iterate( on_element, Odds );
}
```

expected output:

```
Whole range:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 

Should skip specified elements:

0, 4, 5, 

Should traverse only evens:

0, 2, 4, 

Should traverse only odds:

1, 3, 5,
```

Comment: The whole concept of skipping is abstracted out, cool! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a version of `iterate` to take one parameter, you have to implement one.

Comment: or maybe you wanted a default value for second argument like an empty list